# Can't open iframe with File://

Tags: iframe, src

this is my code:

```
<iframe src="file://142.116.7.26/Ress/altamira/index.html" width="100%" height="800" scrolling="no" align="top" frameborder="0" >
```

Error Inline Frames

```
</iframe>
```

so... I can't open the web in the iframe, why!? If I use a link with the code calling:

```
href="file://142.116.7.26/Ress/altamira/index.html"
```

It works.. but with the Iframe can't get anything. I have the Info in safety server.

Answer (score 1):

All modern browsers should prevent display of "local" files using the `file` protocol in iframes for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You specify "file:" but then the rest of the url has a hostname/IP address in it. If it really is a file on the same machine where you are running the browser, then it should have file:/// and a file path, with no hostname/IP address